# mv folder1 folder2 and files dissapear

Tags: mv

Executed the line

```
mv Scenery myTakes
```

where both `Scenery` and `myTakes` are directories. While `Scenery` was renamed to `myTakes`, I was pleasantly surprised to find the new directory empty.

I'm wondering baffled what happened to those files and why this didn't work.
Thanks guys.

Comment: Assuming both really are directories, you should now have a folder `Scenery` within `myTakes`. Is that really not the case?

Comment: You say `Scenery` and `myTakes` are both directories, but then you say `Scenery` was renamed to `myTakes`. But, the latter would only happen if `myTakes` did not exist. Otherwise, `Scenery` would have been moved into `myTakes` to be `myTakes/Scenery`. Please clarify.

Comment: Find your files with `ls -lR myTakes`.

Comment: Scenery did not exist.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways `mv` handles

```
mv folder1 folder2
```

If `folder2` does not exist, `folder1`'s name is changed to `folder2`.

If `folder2` exists (and is a directory (the Unix/Linux word for "folder" is "directory")),  `folder1` keeps its name, and is moved into `folder2`, as `folder2/folder1`.

There is a known pitfall for newbies with `mv`. If one does

```
mv a b c
```

and `c` is a directory, `a` and `b` are renamed to `c/a` and `c/b`. This is good.

However, if `c` is a file, hilarity ensues:

File `a` is renamed `c`, the old `c` is lost, then `b` is also renamed to `c` and the former `a` is also lost.

Either "be careful" (ensure that the rightmost parameter to `mv` is a directory) or use the "`--target-directory=`" option to `mv`.

Read `man mv`.

Comment: I can't reproduce your example. I created three files and tried `mv a b c` and it failed with `mv: target 'c' is not a directory` Am I missing something?

Comment: No, I just acquired my habits before `mv` was improved to detect the "last arg is a file" error.

Comment: Thanks for the -t. That option does drop the file into the intended directory. I've opted to doing something similar which is us the '/' which is similar to a -t.